# How to recover a deleted branch in Azure DevOps git without knowing the "exact" name

Tags: git, azure-devops

I think I deleted a branch (locally and remote) few days ago in Azure DevOps (git repo). I know it is possible to restore if I knew the "exact name", but what if I didn't remember it entirely? Is there any activity logs I can refer to get the full name? Any Idea?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/restore-deleted-branch?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Answer (score 5):

Look for the id of the revision of the tip of the branch you want to *recover* on `git reflog`. Then you can use that id (checkout, create a branch on it, whatever).